# How to generate thread-safe pdf with mod_wsgi/django/python

Tags: python, django, pdf, mod-wsgi, thread-safety

I have a web site all developed in Django 1.4 / Python 2.7 and need a way to generate thread safe pdfs (= need to be able to generate concurrent pdf files). Need support for adding graphic/png and all reports are typically tables and lots of tables.

Running wsgi / Apache on webfaction.

What is the best lib to use (currently using reportlab and due to that it is not thread safe I need to replace it ASAP...).

/ Jens

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [pdfnet sdk](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/index.html)? They have python bindings, and I've had success using them. You can download a trial version, and get started. They are somewhat lower level though, so you'll find your self building textruns and other pdf elements, with all the quirks therein.

Comment: Thanks, have contacted them !